# how to safely convert datetime from web input for schedule job in elixir, phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to get a date and time information from front end using datetime picker. so in my controller.

```
def show(conn, %{"date" => date, "time" => time}) do
# date value will be "2018-09-29"
# time value will be "12:00"
end
```

in functino, how can I properly build datetime in naive datetime format like this?

```
 ~N[2018-09-29 12:00:00]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you have almost matches ISO 8601; just join the date and time, append `:00`, and pass it to `NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601`:

```
iex(1)> date = "2018-09-29"
"2018-09-29"
iex(2)> time = "12:00"
"12:00"
iex(3)> NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601("#{date} #{time}:00")
{:ok, ~N[2018-09-29 12:00:00]}
```